# Twitch Chat Bot program not responding

Tags: python, chatbot, twitch, openai-api, gpt-3

I am trying to make a python program which takes twitch chat as input, uses gpt3 to generate response, then say that response using pyttsx3 library. When running the program, it is neither responding to the chat nor showing any error. I am not able to tell if the program is actually connected with twitch or not. Here's the code -

```
import openai
import pyttsx3
import asyncio
from twitchio.ext import commands

# Initialize OpenAI API
openai.api_key = ""

# Initialize the text to speech engine
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty('voice', 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_EN-US_ZIRA_11.0')


def generate_response(prompt):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="text-davinci-003",
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=4000,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=0.5,
    )
    return response["choices"][0]["text"]


def speak_text(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


async def main():
    bot = commands.Bot(
        # set up the bot
        token='',
        irc_token='',
        client_id='',
        nick='',
        prefix='!',
        initial_channels=['disappointed_aether']
    )

    @bot.event
    async def event_message(ctx):
        print("Received a message")
        if ctx.author.name.lower() != bot.nick.lower():
            print(ctx.content)

            # Generate the response
            response = generate_response(ctx.content)
            print(f"chat gpt 3 says: {response}")

            # read response using GPT3
            speak_text(response)

    await bot.start()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

First I thought asyncio might be causing the problem, so tried to change the last 3 lines to

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run()
```

This did not work. Other than that, I honestly have no idea what is causing the problem. Please help